# How to save images into specific folder in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, ios9.1, phphotolibrary

Already have answers, for saving images into specific folder by using **ALAssetsLibrary**. But it is deprecated in iOS 9.0 and giving warning **"Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead"**.

When i change ALAssetsLibrary into PHPhotoLibrary getting the error at this point.

```
    [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"myAlbum" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
```

*error

```
 No visible @interface for 'PHPhotoLibrary' declares the selector 'saveImage:toAlbum:withCompletionBlock:'
```

How to save images into specific folder By Using **PHPhotoLibrary** (or) any other solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348450/phphotolibrary-error-while-saving-image-at-url for some discussion on the topic specifically using PHPhotoLibrary as an API.

Comment: seen that link... saving images is ok ...but my requirement is to save into specific folder

Comment: check my answer below, updated to show how to put binary image data into specific folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used `PHPhotoLibrary` yet but I know the old school way of saving photos in Obj-C using the local documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = paths.firstObject;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,imageFolder];

BOOL isDir;
NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath isDirectory:&isDir])
    if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:imagePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
        NSLog(@"Error: folder creation failed %@", documentsDirectory);

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imagePath, imageName] contents:nil attributes:nil];
[imageData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imagePath, imageName] atomically:YES];
```

To retrieve that image from the NSDocumentDirectory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = paths.firstObject;
NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentDirectory, imagePath]; // image path is same as above
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    return image;
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: what is imageFolder ? and imageName ? ...i am using imagePickerController

Comment: These are strings that you create. imagePickerController will return the image to you as a UIImage out of the delegate methods for the class. You can decide what to do with it from there.

Comment: Ya got it . We should mention our own folder name and image name right

Comment: Can you tell me how to fetch saved image from Document Directory

Comment: @ChandanReddy i will update my answer above shortly.

Comment: Thank You @dokun1 i will check it.

Comment: Change line from "NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentDirectory, imagePath];" to NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", documentDirectory, imageFolder,fileName]; because imagePath already have documentDirectory. so it is wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is not Method named like this.

For saving images to the PHPhotoLibrary you need to create an Asset. See

[Which PHAssetCollection to use for saving an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065774/which-phassetcollection-to-use-for-saving-an-image)

for detailed informations.

Comment: Ya seen ...but i want to save into separate folder